# How to make two instance of selenium safaridriver?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safaridriver

How can i make two instance of selenium driver ?? i used these codes and i am having a problem.

```
        SafariDriver sf = new SafariDriver();

        sf.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://marathonbet.com/");

        SafariDriver sf2 = new SafariDriver();

        sf2.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://bet365.com/");
```

here is the screenshot: http://sdrv.ms/1fDzQYT

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Anything special about your SafariDriver setup? Also I think Safari for Windows is dead, what's the point of testing it on Windows?

Comment: actually i was asking for help

Comment: Have you tried executing other actions on the other browser that did not navigate? Does it respond to anything?

Answer (score 0):

you can instantiate 2 instance of selenium webdriver, use the code below.

```
    WebDriver sf1 = new SafariDriver(); 
    sf1.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://marathonbet.com/");
    WebDriver sf2 = new SafariDriver();
    sf2.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://bet365.com/");
```

You need to instantiate WebDriver object with SafariDriver, that you were not doing correctly.

Comment: i already tried this but it turns out it only navigates to the first instance

Comment: I've tried, and its working fine for me... 2 webpages are opened in 2 different browsers.